# Is the LocalBusiness schema strict to business that you have ownsership?

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I work for a company that list small local business from a niche market in a website. Most of these companies have little infrastructure on the internet. So to improve visibility we are adding the Schema.org Local Business in their profiles.

We looked in the [schema specification](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) and the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-businesses), but it isn't explicit anything about local business ownership. So it is not clear if this structured data allows listing other local businesses instead of your own.

Is it okay to use this schema to create rich snippet cards if you don't own the company? Can this have negative outcome as a Search Engine Optimization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions belong on [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing structured data about other businesses (or any other domain) is perfectly fine. Structured data is useful for the content on your pages, not just for the entities that publish this content.

A consumer (like Google) that offers features making use of this structured data (like rich results) has its own rules for this feature, of course. But even if the consumer would support this feature only for structured data about the author’s own business, this should not stop you from providing the structured data about other businesses.

As a general rule: You provide as much structured data as you can/want, and consumers pick out what they want to use.

To convey that it’s not your own business, you can provide your own `LocalBusiness` as [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher)/[`author`](http://schema.org/author) of the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), which is [`about`](http://schema.org/about) the other `LocalBusiness`.

```html
<body typeof="schema:WebPage">

  <header property="schema:author schema:publisher" typeof="schema:LocalBusiness">
    <h1 property="schema:name">Your own business</h1>
  </header>

  <article property="schema:about" typeof="schema:LocalBusiness">
    <h2 property="schema:name">The other business</h2>
  </article>

</body>
```

Comment: I do not understand, why this answer has a downvote. The answer is correct and relevant. Please elaborate. In the meantime, I'll upvote.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks, Stefan. As the question also has one downvote and  one close vote, my guess it that it comes from someone who thinks that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, probably because of the SEO side question (which, in fact, is off-topic), but as it’s not the primary focus of the question, I think it’s fine.

Comment: I haven't tought about using our LocalBusiness as a author of the WebPage. Regardless of the consumer goal, having the LocalBusiness in the WebPage and in the company profile solves the ambiguity of the data.

Comment: Up vote because it is a quality answer with explanation and advice (as is usual for @unor)